# Let $x_n$ denote the smallest integer such that $\sum\limits_{k=n}^{x_n} \frac 1k >1$, then $x_n\sim en$

Tags: sequences-and-series, harmonic-numbers

> For $n\geq 2$, let $x_n$ denote the smallest integer such that $\displaystyle \sum_{k=n}^{x_n} \frac 1k >1$. Prove that $\lim_n \frac{x_n}{n}\sim e$.

I've found this problem in an old handout of mine. $x_n$ is well-defined since the harmonic series diverges. By definition of $x_n$, $\sum_{k=n}^{x_n-1} \frac 1k\leq 1$ and $\sum_{k=n}^{x_n} \frac 1k >1$, thus $$1+\frac{1}{x_n}\geq \sum_{k=n}^{x_n} \frac 1k >1$$

That's all I've found so far.

Comment: Use the fact that the $n$th harmonic number $$H_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k$$ is such that $$H_n-\log n\to\gamma$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combine your inequalities with integral inequalities to get

$$\int_n^{x_n-1}\frac1t~{\rm d}t<\sum_{k=n}^{x_n-1}\frac1k<1<\sum_{k=n}^{x_n}\frac1k<\frac1n+\int_n^{x_n}\frac1t~{\rm d}t$$

Evaluating gives us

$$\ln\left(\frac{x_n}n-\frac1n\right)<1<\frac1n+\ln\left(\frac{x_n}n\right)$$

Solving for $x_n/n$ gives us

$$\exp\left(1-\frac1n\right)<\frac{x_n}n<e+\frac1n$$

And as $n\to\infty$, we get the squeeze desired.

Comment: Beautiful answer